# Unwanted Wave-like Shades in the Background as the Object Moves

Tags: rendering

I have made a smoothed studio-like setup
and spot light linked to my object.

[image]

The Object turns round itself for few seconds and then moves forward toward the camera

(I have marked them in the second photo, though it's a bit hard to see in only one picture).

[image]

As the object moves forward, some unwanted wave-liked shades appear in the background and move. Do you know what is causing the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide the blend file. Just upload it on https://pasteall.org/blend/  and share the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing in which format you are rendering and what quality settings you use it's hard to tell the exact reason, but these are no shades depending on the animation itself or the render settings, I guess. These effects are called *Banding*, *Colour Banding* or *Posterization* and can appear in all kinds of software or images. It's usually a problem of insufficient bit depth to display smooth color transitions.  The reason for the low quality can be high compression in image or video formats for example.

Short articles on these topics:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterization

Comment: Hi Gordon,
This is exactly the problem. Thanks for your detailed answer. I am working on that.

Comment: Glad it helped. You might consider to mark the answer as accepted then so that others know there is a solution.